# Audio bitrate in YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, mp3

This video clip:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wc0PB6Azwn0

What is the max audio bitrate and how to detect real audio bitrate? is it the same? Please no rumors and no guessing.

Does it depend on the video quality I am watching (1080p, 720p, etc)?
If you say - yes, it makes no sense, because the clip was uploaded at one bitrate only.

Hope, someone who knows the subject can answer that questions.
Is it possible to detect the audio bitrate from YouTube video at all?
Stats for nerds is useless, it shows no audio bitrate.
Taking consideration lossy (vs lossless) audio max is 320 Kbps, it cannot be higher than that by definition.

Anyone who knows?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the command line tool [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/) to list all available transcodings for a given YouTube video by running `youtube-dl -F <url-to-your-video>`.

Example output using the URL mentioned in your question:
[image: youtube-dl output]

Studying the output we can see that the audio transcoding with the highest bitrate is "format 251" using the opus codec at an average bitrate of around 145k. Note that YouTube is not using a fixed bitrate but rather a variable bitrate with target of  ~160k.

The opus codec is currently supported in [most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=opus) (but not Safari). Browsers without support for opus will fallback to the m4a stream at a variable bitrate targeting ~128k.

If you want to make 100% sure which audio transcoding you're currently listening to, you can right click the YouTube video player and select "Stats for nerds" and look for the number mentioned in the codecs section and cross-reference that with the output given by youtube-dl:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Does it depend on the video quality I am watching (1080p, 720p, etc)? If you say - yes, it makes no sense, because the clip was uploaded at one bitrate only.

Yes, it depends on video quality.  When you're choosing a video quality, you're not just choosing the video quality...  you're choosing the audio quality as well.  YouTube isn't giving you the option, but it's part of the package.

Videos aren't served as-is, they're transcoded.  You upload your video and it's re-compressed at a variety of different bitrates with different settings.

Your audio bitrate depends on what YouTube decided to encode it as.  Each video *may* have many versions of the stream.

The best thing you can do is get a build of FFmpeg with libquvi enabled, and let it parse the page, find the streams, download the stream, demux, and figure things out for you from there.

> Taking consideration lossy (vs lossless) audio max is 320 Kbps, it cannot be higher than that by definition.

Your definition is wrong.  There are all kinds of lossy audio codecs, and they can be ran at a variety of bitrates.

Comment: I was talking about YouTube audio. Wait a second it really doesnt make sense. So, you are saying, the same video clip, if I open it with 480P or 1080P will have a different audio quality? So, how come all these audiot YouTube downloader/converter apps, web and not only, (4K Video Downloader app, for example) only ask to provide a URL of a video, not a resolution? And they offer to download an mp3 from a video in various bitrates? How is that possible to get a higher bitrate than an original audio?

Comment: Also, when I said video quality, I was talking about video quality Setting on YouTube, not the quality of original video.

Comment: @monstro Yes, if you open a 480p video or a 1080p video on YouTube it *can* have different audio quality.  Most of those downloader apps are just going to pick the best quality stream and snag that.  For the MP3, they're probably transcoding it as YouTube doesn't use MP3 for audio.  You can have a higher bitrate than the original audio simply by transcoding it with a higher bitrate.  There's of course no benefit to this.  What I was saying is that there are codecs that support a higher bitrate than 320kbit.